# Find package number based on list of products

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

So I have a spreadsheet which shows product packages and products in it

| Package | Product |
| --- | --- |
| Package1 | Product1 |
| Package1 | Product2 |
| Package1 | Product3 |
| Package2 | Product1 |
| Package2 | Product3 |
| Package3 | Product2 |
| Package4 | Product1 |
| Package4 | Product2 |

Now I need to backtrace which package was sent to the client given I have a list of products.
So if I put somewhere two lines:

|  |
| --- |
| Product1 |
| Product2 |

I need to see result being

- Package4

It could even list all the packages showing a number of matches for a product and how good the match is

| Package # | matches | Exact? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Package 4 | 2 | EXACT |
| Package 1 | 2 | NOT EXACT |
| Package 2 | 1 | NOT EXACT |
| Package 3 | 1 | NOT EXACT |

I was trying to play with VLOOKUP and INDEX/MATCH but couldn't come up with a good result.
Ideally This all should happen on the separate sheet where I can enter my products in some designated cell(s) and get results in another cell(s). There are like 180 packages with with 400 products total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be using the newest functions:

[image]

Formula in `F1`:

```
=LET(A,UNIQUE(A2:A9),B,D2:D3,C,BYROW(A,LAMBDA(a,SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A9,a,B2:B9,B)))),D,BYROW(A,LAMBDA(a,SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A9,a)))),E,IF((C=D)*(D=COUNTA(B)),"","NOT ")&"EXACT",VSTACK({"Package #","Matches","Exact?"},SORTBY(HSTACK(A,C,E),E,,C,-1,A,)))
```

I you don't yet got access to `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` you can use:

```
=LET(A,UNIQUE(A2:A9),B,D2:D3,C,BYROW(A,LAMBDA(a,SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A9,a,B2:B9,B)))),D,BYROW(A,LAMBDA(a,SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A9,a)))),E,IF((C=D)*(D=COUNTA(B)),"","NOT ")&"EXACT",SORTBY(CHOOSE({1,2,3},A,C,E),E,,C,-1,A,))
```

The downside is that this is now without headers.

Comment: oh wow, that's way beyond my Excel knowledge, although I'm getting #NAME? as a result. looks like my office Windows PC has a version of Excel that doesn't support LAMBDA, but I also tried on a latest Office 365 on Mac and getting the same.

Comment: @frankazoid that's because these BETA functions are not for Mac yet. Unfortunately

Comment: Excel on Mac recognizes them though. when i type =BYROW( or =LAMBDA( it shows details on those functions. Windows doesn't do even that. Any chance you can recommend another way to get what I need?

Comment: It's the `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` that won't work. I can add an alternative but then it's without headers. @frankazoid. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

A very long shot, but this does the trick in Office365 without Beta formulas or Lambda.

```
=LET(data,A1:B8,
     x,C1:C2,
          a,INDEX(data,,1),
          ua,UNIQUE(a),
     cu,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(a)=ua),SEQUENCE(ROWS(a),,1,0)),
          udata,UNIQUE(data),
                uda,INDEX(udata,,1),
                udb,INDEX(udata,,2),
          fuda,FILTER(uda,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(x)=udb),SEQUENCE(ROWS(x),,1,0))),
     cp,MMULT(--(TRANSPOSE(fuda)=ua),SEQUENCE(ROWS(fuda),,1,0)),
FILTER(ua,(cp=ROWS(x))*(cu=ROWS(x))))
```

[image]

It gets the unique values from column A (`ua`) and counts the number the unique value appears in column a (`cu`).

Then - to cope with duplicates giving false  count results - I filter the data into unique data (`udata`).
This is used to filter the first column of this unique data (`uda`) with a `MMULT()` of the search values (`x`) against the unique data column B (`udb`).
This results in the count of unique values in column A where (unique) column B matches the search values. The counter is called `cp`.

Finally a filter is set over the unique values of column A where the count of the search values equals the counter `cu` and equals the counter `cp`.